# Chef execution order for this recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have following chef recipe.

```
lazy_message = 'Hello world'
file 'lazy_message' do
  path '/tmp/lazy.txt'
  content "#{lazy_message}"
end 

execute 'yum-makecache' do
  command 'yum makecache'
  notifies :create, 'file[message]', :immediately
  action :nothing
end

package 'bind-utils' do
  action :install
  notifies :run, 'execute[yum-makecache]', :before
end

file 'message' do
  path '/tmp/message.txt'
  content lazy { "#{lazy_message}" }
end

lazy_message = 'Goodbye world'
```

When I run it, it is executed in the following order.

```
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
         - lcd_web (0.1.0)
       Installing Cookbook Gems:
       Compiling Cookbooks...
       Converging 4 resources
       Recipe: lcd_web::default
         * file[lazy_message] action create
           - create new file /tmp/lazy.txt
           - update content in file /tmp/lazy.txt from none to 64ec88
           --- /tmp/lazy.txt    2018-07-28 07:47:39.433257401 +0000
           +++ /tmp/.chef-lazy20180728-296-7usgw7.txt   2018-07-28 07:47:39.433257401 +0000
           @@ -1 +1,2 @@
           +Hello world
         * execute[yum-makecache] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
         * yum_package[bind-utils] action install
           - install version 32:9.9.4-61.el7.x86_64 of package bind-utils
         * file[message] action create
           - create new file /tmp/message.txt
           - update content in file /tmp/message.txt from none to b4dabd
           --- /tmp/message.txt 2018-07-28 07:47:52.115780144 +0000
           +++ /tmp/.chef-message20180728-296-tgnjuk.txt    2018-07-28 07:47:52.115780144 +0000
           @@ -1 +1,2 @@
           +Goodbye world
         * execute[yum-makecache] action run
           - execute yum makecache
         * file[message] action create (up to date)
```

I do not understand the order of execution with use of lazy block, : before and : immediately directives.

According to me following shall be the order of execution.

- Execute file 'lazy message'
- go to yum 'makecache' but skips it  due to action nothing
- go to bind-utils but  jump to execute 'yum-makecache' again due to :before directive and runs it.
- runs  file 'message'  due to :immediatelyn in 'yum-makecache'
- now runs bind-utils
- runs file 'message' again.

But actual output is not like that 'bind-utils' is running  before 'yum-makecache'

Answer (score 0):

`before` notifications are super finicky and basically only to be used for stopping a service before package/file updates on platforms where you can't do an upgrade of a running service. Hanging further notifications off a before timing is definitely going to do illogical things, we don't test nor care about the behavior of that since I've never heard of an actual reason to do that. Remember that Chef is already order sensitive, you don't use `:before` to enforce ordering, it's only for that kind of upgrade situation really.